# How can I place items in a relative order inside a FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a background picture that has in it's center another, smaller, picture. I would like to add some text just below the smaller picture (middle_image). But this text should NOT be  at the bottom of the background image. Here is a link showing how I would like the end result to be like: http://postimg.org/image/6ft6tgamd/

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/messageSource"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#ff0000">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/background_img"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_image" />

            <eCity.Mobile.Android.CircularImageView
                android:id="@+id/middle_image"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:src="@drawable/middle_image" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you want to use `FrameLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`? `RelativeLayout` would be perfect for this type of layout. If you want the `FrameLayout` too, you could just put the `RelativeLayout` within the `FrameLayout`, but that would be less efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official Document ion says-

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display 
>   a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single
>   child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a
>   way that's scalable to different screen sizes without  the children
>   overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a
>   FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by
>   assigning gravity to each child.

Better option is to choose an `RelativeLayout` you can adjust your code like this-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#c6727272" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileImage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/date"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="HIgh School Reunion Dinner"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/venue"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="June 25 , 8:00PM"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/venue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Cafe Ruby's,DMA Square"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose, there is `LinearLayout` (or `RelativeLayout`).

And, you don't have to use independent `ImageView` for background image. `ViewGroups` (`LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout`, etc) can be set background itself.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/messageSource"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_image" />

    <eCity.Mobile.Android.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/middle_image"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/middle_image" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text1" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text2" />

</LinearLayout>
```